# PHP- fopen - open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php, safe-mode

I have moved my website to another hosting server. However, there is a little problem with fopen() function. Every time it is run, it is resulting with the following error:

> Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir
>   restriction in effect.
>   File(/home/www-virtual/www-username/www/bindata/gallery/GAL34e81b4adce22091c6ee31c71055e181.jpg)
>   is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (/www/default/www:/www/username_www:/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php-5.2/lib)
>   in /www/username_www/www/frontend/gallery/GalleryPage.php5 on line 112

I can't do anything with the PHP script because it is ionCube encoded.

What is left to do then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change hosting companies now!

If they can't configure open_basedir correctly who know what other horrors lie in wait (yes, it might be valid for them to apply a blanket restriction - but if that were the case here why have they included someone else's dir in the whitelist).

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer (from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223800/how-can-i-relax-phps-open-basedir-restriction)) is to set an exception to PHP's [open basedir](http://au.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) in a .htaccess file

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs>
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs:/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/zend"
</Directory>
```

you can also completely remove the restriction with

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs>
php_admin_value open_basedir none
</Directory>
```

Comment: If they've restricted the open basedir (albeit that they've got it WRONG) then they should have blocked htaccess overrides.

Comment: @symcbean I agree, but it's worth a shot.  If it fails then probably the only option is to move hosting companies or try the hard the task of getting the current hosts to change their policy.

Comment: Is it possible that somewhere in those encoded PHP files, is the absolute path?